# Mozzplugger not working in Lubuntu 11.10

Tags: pdf, browser

I'd like to open a PDF in a Firefox tab. I've been able to do it with MozPlugger before updating to 11.10.

`preferences -> applications`

now scroll down, then I see `always ask` next to `file`.

I guess I need to change `always ask` to `MozPlugger`. To do that I need to find out where MozPlugger is. However, it wasn't in `.mozilla`.

Am I doing the right thing? How can I find out where MozPlugger is?

=======================================================================

*FIX*

`sudo gnome-open /etc/mozpluggerrc`      # need to be root to edit

Find a pdf block and change to the [following](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/get-embedded-pdf-files-in-firefox-36-4.html):

```
application/pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/postscript: ps: PostScript file
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"
```

Open firefox's **help** 
-> **Troubleshooting Information** 
-> Click on **Open Containing Folder**
-> Delete **pluginreg.dat** ([You may need to delete your local $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/pluginreg.dat file for mozplugger to be enabled correctly after you update it. (It will get regenerated)](http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/))

The last step was necessary for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix that might not apply to your problem. It did solve my similar issue.

### Checking you have the same problem :

- Type `about:plugins` in a firefox adress bar.
- Search for a **MozPlugger** category.

If you have the same problem I had they should be no such category.

### Solving the problem :

- open firefox's **help** -> **Troubleshooting Information**
- Click on **Open Containing Folder**
- Edit **pluginreg.dat**
- At the end of the file, in a category called `[INVALID]`, you should find 2 lines ressembling this :

> ```
> can'tRememberWhat/mozplugger.so:$ 
> lot'sOfNumbers:$
> ```

- Cut those lines and paste them just under the `[PLUGINS]` category.

Restart firefox and everything should be fixed.

Comment: In `about:plugins` there was the **MozPlugger** category, though pdf was not mentioned there.

Comment: In **pluginreg.dat** there was nothing under [invalid].

Comment: However, in `about:plugins`, I found it says "For documentation on how to configure mozplugger, check the man page. (type man mozplugger)".

Comment: In `man mozplugger`, it suggests to edit **mozpluggerrc**.
So I googled **mozpluggerrc** and found the fragments of solution.

Comment: @Robin002 well done finding a fix to your problem ! :)